# DELL Optiplex 7080 taking multiple times to start

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-20.04, dualboot, dell-optiplex

I've a brand new DELL Optiplex 7080 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot. But the problem is that sometimes it takes multiple times to start. Why this happends and how to fix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Many years ago Dell tech support agents used to recommended "draining residual charge" for those cases. Not sure if still applicable but you have nothing to lose: Disconnect power cable and press and hold power button for about 15-30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> I've a brand new DELL Optiplex 7080 .....   that sometimes it takes
> multiple times to start.

Contact Dell Support and ask them. There could be a hardware or disk error causing it not to start smoothly.

It should not matter which OS is being started.

They may wish to supply a replacement model as the easiest solution.